# Переключение веб плееров на сайте и вытаскивание ссылок на видеофайлы

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, парсер

Приложение, которое хочу сделать парсит страницы сайта с сериалами. С поиском, сортировкой сериалов разобрался. При выборе сериала бросает на страницу с детальной информацией и плеерами. Плееры переключаются с помощью кнопок на странице. С помощью кнопок выбирается серия. Спарсить ссылку можно только первой серии, потому как активирован первый плеер и выбрана первая серия. Что можно использовать для переключения плееров и серий?

Comment: Попробуйте selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте Selenium и браузер, или если это возможно посмотрите, как генерируется ссылка на серию, может там подставляется 1,2,3,4 в url как номер серии

Comment: Selenium и браузер возможно хорошо на Виндоус и Линукс, но как сделать запуск на андроид? Ругается на Path. Посмотрел, что можно скачать драйвер и закинуть его в папку со скриптом. Но драйвера только на десктопы.

Comment: Попробуйте PhantoJS. Я конечно далёк от Андроид разработки, но мне кажется что лучше сделать парсинг на сервере, а приложению отдавать готовые URL'ы. В таком варианте рассматриваете? А то мне кажется что подобный парсинг делать на смартфоне это слишком жирно, и не укладывается в " энергоэффективность".

Comment: Буду пробовать. Главное есть уже от чего отталкиваться.